# image file reading in system verilog

Tags: system-verilog

I have written system verilog code for reading data from an image file (800*600 -
    *.raw).
    The file actually contains 800 * 600 * 3 bytes. But my code can only read upto almost 
    half the data.
    After that the read data seems to be "00".
    Valuable suggestions for resolving this is appreciated..

```
My code is as follows.


//`define EOF 32'hFFFF_FFFF
//`define EOF \n

reg [7:0]data_byte;

class input_video_IF;
int count;
integer input_file, fread_return,output_file;


function new ();

input_file = $fopen("test_800.raw","r");
if(input_file)
begin
$display("File OPENED");
end
else
begin
$display("File error");
end

output_file = $fopen("output_800.raw", "w");
endfunction:new

task image_file_read();
count = 0;
//while (!$feof(input_file))
while(count != 1440000)
begin
fread_return = $fread(data_byte,input_file);
count++;
$display("%d %h",count,data_byte);
//$fwrite(output_file,data_byte);
end
$finish;
$fclose(input_file);
endtask : image_file_read

endclass

program Image_read_test;
int input_file;
input_video_IF In_IF = new();
initial

In_IF.image_file_read();


endprogram
```

Comment: Some minor comments about your code: `data_byte` should not be defined outside of the class. `count` doesn't need to be a class field. Both of these two variables could be defined locally inside the `image_file_read()` task. Also, `image_file_read()` doesn't consume time, so maybe it should rather be a function.

Comment: Are you sure you have a file that's big enough?